# jQuery drag and drop ul and li elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

On one hand I got list of `<ul>` and `<li>`. The `<ul>` and `<li>` elements should be dragged and droped. The target is a `div` or `span`. How could I get started?

Comment: If you use jquery, why don't use it library documentation ?

Comment: -1 for showing no initial effort. SO works best in a re-active manner (e.g. "Why can't I drop this UL into this DIV?").

Comment: This question is so old, yet you did not even mark an answere as correct. no initial effort shown, >16k views, top google search result, you destroy this community sir. everybody, downvote pls

Answer (score 5):

Basically your draggables would be the `<li>` elements and your droppable will be the `<div>` or `<span>` or both. Set the necessary options for both the draggable and the droppable. Afterwards handle the drag event of the draggable and the drop event of the droppable in order to perform any custom functionality. Validate drop elements with the accept option of the droppable (it's either a selector or a function). Here is the necessary documentation:

Draggable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Droppable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

jsFillde: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGWTS/1/)

Comment: ok, but do you have any example link smiler to my question answer?

Comment: Absolutely, updating with fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

well this will give you a start

[Jquery UI droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart)

Answer (score 0):

Use the documentation of jQueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/

For your question: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable