# Making the `<li>` elements draggable and droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've created a form, where there is a side-nav bar. When a `<li>` is clicked, its corresponding modal will appear. This is how I've shown my side-nav bar:

```
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-nav_wrapper">
                 <h4 class="sidebar-brand">Select Field Type</h4>
              <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="margin-top: 40px;">
                 <li><a href="#" id="SingleLine_LI" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SingleLine_Modal">Single Line</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PickList_Modal">Pick List</a></li>       
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-nav_wrapper">
              <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="margin-top: 40px; margin-left: -20px;">
                 <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Date_Modal">Date</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Time_Modal">Time</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
```

So, whenever a `<li>` is clicked, a modal will open. Now, I want to make it draggable and droppable. This is how I tried to do:

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="div_container"></div>
   <div id="log">
$('li').draggable({
            revert: 'invalid'          
         });

         $('.div_container').droppable({
            accept: 'li',
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                alert('inside');                
            },
            over: function (event, ui) {
                $('#log').text('over');
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                $('#log').text('out');
            }
        });
```

What happened was, I was able to drag the `<li>` element, but couldn't bring it outside the side-nav bar. It gets dragged inside the side-nav itself and all the `<li>` elements gets disappeared. I don't know what's wrong and how to make that happen. What should I change? How can I bring that outside and drop inside the div?

Comment: Please check this one. [jQuery drag and drop ul and li elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242737/jquery-drag-and-drop-ul-and-li-elements)

Comment: @Husen I tried my code with the help of that que only. That made my `<li>` elements draggable, but I couldn't drop it exactly inside that div. That's the prob here

Comment: @Maximus: What's that and how should it be done?

Comment: @duddosai, [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) you can setup an env where people can go and debug the case