# How to append div outside of each list item using j-query?

Tags: jquery, dom, model-view-controller

I have a `<li>` tags inside `<ul>` i want to put each `<li>` tag inside `<div>` tag like `<div><li></li></div>`

how can i achieve this using jquery or JS.

Comment: Putting `<div>` around `<li>` would produce invalid (i.e. non-standards conforming) html. The W3C validator tells me **Element div not allowed as child of element ul**.

Comment: @PeterB I want to make this <li> draggable that's why I am doing it

Comment: `<li>` can be made draggable just fine, see the fiddle linked in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242831/1220550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [wrap](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```js
$('ul li').wrap('<div></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Test A</li>
    <li>Test B</li>
</ul>
```

but this will not be a valid HTML, [W3C](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) will give you this error

> Error: Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: i want to make this <li> draggable that's why I am doing it

Comment: @nado1122 just saying. Is this solution works for you ?

Comment: @nado1122 don't know what the problem with `$('ul li').draggable();` is

Comment: $('ul li').draggable(); its not working as i am using listboxfor() html helper.